# Rails3 twitter-bootstrap-rails with multiple layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm running Rails3 with twitter-bootstrap-rails. I have 2 different layouts "application.html.erb" and "backend.html.erb". Unfortunately, when using the backend layout I still get all the bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less styles overriding the defaults. I would like to only use a separate overrides file so the layout is different than my application layout.

Any suggestion on how best to do this?

The only way I can think to do this is to not require the override file in my application.css file (as suggested in the bootstrap readme) and instead require it in a CSS file that I only load in the application.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see that the application layout actually specified the application.css file. I modified that line to read:

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "backend", :media => "all" %>
```

And then created a backend.css file that did not reference the entire tree nor the original overrides file.

Now I have a generic layout that can be customized through the backend.css or my new bootstrap_and_overrides_backend.css.less file.